# weblogic Error 500--Internal Server Error

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, wicket

I am having a 500 error code with weblogic 10.3 while trying to load a web page with my web application.

Here is the log in my weblogic server

```
    Apr 29, 2014 8:46:11 AM CDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020>     <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@142ef25 - appName: '_appsdir_MyApp_ear', name: 'MyApp', context-path:
 '/MyApp', spec-version: 'null'] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:643)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycle.onExceptionLoop(WebRequestCycle.java:107)
        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1386)
        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1438)
        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:546)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

and here is what I get in the browser

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycle.onExceptionLoop(WebRequestCycle.java:107)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1386)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1438)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:546)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at com.uprr.ui.wicket.components.infrastructure.RicolaWicketFilter.doFilter(RicolaWicketFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what is wrong. Actually, the page I am loading is fetching data from a DB and they happen to be old data that were even deleted in the DB.